# Python Tkinter ~ canvas.delete()

Tags: image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, self

How can I delete a specific image tag of a canvas with canvas.delete()?
Should I put 'img' as a parameter or is something else required?

```
ball = PhotoImage(file='ball.png')
[Class Name and __init__]
self.canvas.delete('img')
self.canvas.create_image(self.getCoordinates()[0], self.getCoordinates()[1], image=ball)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a canvas object returns an id. You can pass that id to the `delete` method.

```
self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(...)
...
self.canvas.delete(self.image_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to remove an item with a tag, first you need to assign the tag with the `tag` option for `tk.Canvas.create_xxxxx(...,tag='item1')`:

```py
self.canvas.create_image(self.getCoordinates()[0], self.getCoordinates()[1], image=ball, tag='img')
```